# NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval - not calling funciton

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I want to run a timer in the background. So I created a singleton.

The problem is that after the set 5.0 seconds, it does not call the function `timeEnded()`. Xcode proposes to add `@Objc` in front of the function (like this: `@Objc func timeEnded() {...`) to solve some problem (I don't get what, though). But it still doesn't call that function. Any ideas?

```
class TimerService {
    static let instance = TimerService()
    var internalTimer: NSTimer?

    func startTimer() {
        guard internalTimer != nil else {
            return print("timer already started")
        }
        internalTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(TimerService.timeEnded), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    func timeEnded() {
        //NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("timerEnded", object: nil)
        print("timer Ended")
    }
}
```

Comment: please your xcode version

Comment: Do you add the timer to a run loop anywhere? You should also post your code and not a screen shot.

Comment: Xcode 7.3.1 - Sorry, I replaced it with the code. I'm not sure about that loop. But that's related to another question I have: I start the timer in the `viewDidLoad()` method inside my ViewController. And if I run it, I get "timer already started" in the console. Maybe that has something to do with the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never actually start the timer because your `startTimer()` function will always return before reaching the line of code where you create the timer.

In your `guard` statement you only continue the execution of the function if `internalTimer != nil` but the only place where you set the timer is *after* that statement. Thus, your timer is never created and `internalTimer` will always be `nil`.

This should fix your problem:

```
func startTimer() {
    guard internalTimer == nil else {
        return print("timer already started")
    }
    internalTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(TimerService.timeEnded), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Comment: You are correct. I suggest you edit your answer to show the correct guard statement with `timer == nil`

Comment: Good idea! Will do.

Answer (score 2):

Selectors are a feature of Objective-C and can only be used with methods that are exposed to the dynamic Obj-C runtime. You cannot have a selector to a pure Swift method.

If your class inherits from NSObject then its public methods are exposed to Obj-C automatically. Since your class does not inherit from NSObject you have to use the @objc attribute to indicate that you want this method exposed to Obj-C so that it may be called with an Obj-C selector.

#selector() is the new syntax in Swift 2.2. It allows the compiler to check that the selector you're trying to use actually exists. The old syntax is deprecated and will be removed in Swift 3.0.

Comment: Okay, now I understand the error :) That's a start. But the function is still not called, unfortunately

Comment: Actually in iOS 10 you don't need a selector at all. iOS 10 has block-based timers.